# How to customize bash prompt when (de)activating Pyenv?

Tags: python, bash, customization, archlinux, pyenv

When (de)activating Pyenv (on Arch Linux) my customized Bash prompt is modified by adding/removing the name of virtual environment, example:

Before activating:

```
lucas@localhost ~/mycurdir
$
```

After activating:

```
(myvirtualenv)
lucas@localhost ~/mycurdir
$
```

I wanna customize it to this:

```
lucas@localhost ~/mycurdir
(myvirtualenv) $
```

Moreover I wanna change the current directory to another location when deactivating Pyenv. How can I get it?

Thanks in advance.

**PS1:** I think there are some config files for Pyenv where you could custom actions over prompt when (de)activating. I'm looking for them.

If it is not possible, how can I get the name for current virtual env activated? For my previous examples it should be "**myvirtualenv**", because with

```
pyenv version-name
```

I get the version for python linked only, example: **3.7.2**

*Real case:* I've created this virtual env

```
$ cd ~/Projects/Python_3_7_2/QuickPythonBook && pyenv local 3.7.2 && python3.7 -m venv ve_qpb
```

After activating, this command `pyenv vrsion-name` gets this output `3.7.2`

And `pyenv virtualenvs` shows nothing.

Comment: bash prompt is in variable `PS1` - see in terminal `echo $PS1`. You could find `PS1` in function which (de)activate pyenv and change it.

Comment: May you paste a sample code, please?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to source the `activate` script that `venv` creates for you to activate the virtualenv. If you don't like the customizations it gives you, you could just have your own script or bash function to set the same environment variables without customizing the prompt. The trick is in getting it to work. You might be better off just letting it do its thing and then undoing whatever parts you don't want.

Comment: Also: note that *pyenv* and *virtualenv* are different tools, and the *venv* module that's built into modern versions of Python is almost the same as the old *virtualenv*, but not quite.

Comment: I found the files that add the virtual environment name to the prompt - they are called "activate" or some variation of that (multiple files), and they are located in ```($PYENV_ROOT)/versions/X.Y.Z/envs/bin```. I'm not sure that it's worth figuring out how to manipulate the prompt since you will most likely have to do this for each virtual environment you set up with pyenv